# Does Windows 7 include default touchpad drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad, diagnostic

The Elan touchpad (aka trackpad) on a laptop is not responding consistently.

It works normally much of the time, but then suddenly stops responding.  After a few seconds, it will start responding normally again.

This is either a software problem or a hardware problem.

In order to diagnose this issue, I would like to replace the touchpad drivers with generic drivers.

Does Windows 7 include generic touchpad drivers?

Comment: Very simple to test, if you have the installation files for the current driver as backup. Just delete the device in Device Manager and reboot.

Comment: yes, this it a normal ps/2 input device, so the normal PS/2 drivers are used

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you.  Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1239222/how-to-temporarily-switch-touchpad-trackpad-drivers-to-default-windows-7-ps-2